# Querying from PRD Environment When No Replica is Available - Against Best Practice?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

What is the "best practice" approach to querying for reporting purposes when no replica is available and non-production environments have significant data integrity issues?

While restores can occur, they are typically seen as an infrequent occurrence, and isn't truly sustainable if reporting is required daily.

Comment: To be honest, I wonder what the oppinions would be if such question was posted on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). But the answer really depends on stuff we don't know.

Comment: In general it is best practice not to query from production. You should restore a production backup from time to time as a dev environment. In some cases you may also want to obfuscate the data at the same time due to privacy laws to avoid the developers seeing real client details.

Comment: @DaleK To be fair, querying using a separate star/snowflake Data Warehouse was historically the solution (involving a huge amount of ETL processing etc) but with recent advances in OLTP databases (snapshots, columnstore etc), it has been possible in many cases to stick with them for everything, meaning you only have one source of truth. So newer setups often don't have a fully separate reporting infrastructure

Comment: @Charlieface I guess it depends whether OP is asking with regard to reporting, or developing with test data.

Comment: _our other environments are not being well maintained_ So if they WERE well maintained, does that change the need? IMO that issue deserves more focus than your convenience.

Answer (score 1):

As @LukStorms mentioned in the comment, there are lot of unknowns here.

This can vary a lot from organization to organization and the answer also depends on the use case. You really do not need to query the production DB but all you want to see is up to date information which is only available in production database in your case. Below points or questions might be helpful to solve the problem( not necessarily access to prod db) :

1. As the other DB environments are not being maintained and if your database is setup on cloud like AWS. AWS lets you make a copy of prod which is updated/synched and you can query the prod-snapshot instead of the actual live db.
2. A clone( or spin up a temporary copy of production db for testing purposes). something like https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/fundamentals-cloning-a-production-database-to-a-test-server/ba-p/383852
3. Setup an agreement with the DBA to refresh test/non-prod DBs regularly.